# ACF custom field map how do when address is 'Unnamed Road'?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed `ACF custom field plugin` and I added map custom field. It works well but when I set 'Unnamed Road' from Wordpress, it returns an empty map without pin locator. There is a way that returns a map with pin locator in the right position and the possibility of change address `'Unnamed Road'` in the other custom name?

Comment: Is 'Unnamed Road' a real place? Or why did you set it? (Or I don't get the question)

Comment: yes it  is. There is a place in the maps that haven't a name, but have lat and lng

Comment: Do you also set the lat and lng?

Comment: Yes I've done a variable $map that is egual to `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'map',true)` and it works but the problem is  when there isn't an address and so 'Unnamed Road'

Comment: There might be billions of places named 'Unnamed Road' so make sure you pass the latlng

Comment: yes but I'd change 'Unnamed Road? address with a custom address. For esample I'd change with the name of post which the map refers. I can do this?

Comment: @MichaelBenzo - Could you give us two ```var_dump``` of ```get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'map',true)```. One for "Unnamed Road" and another for a valid address of your choice (i.e 123 Buckingham Palace Road, London, United Kingdom).

Comment: thank all, I've solved. It was a problem with a php function